# Using UItableView In UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have Used Two `TableViews` in `UICollectionView`.My `UicollectionViewCell` Is Of Size 1000*630.When i swipe left on new cell,I want to show Different `Tableview` data corresponding to `UIlabel` in `CollectionViewCell`.I have tried but The data is not displaying
.Where i have to reload `UITableView` ? i am not getting.
Here is my code.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UICollectionViewCell *collectionViewCell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath ];



UILabel *artistOneOfTableOne=(UILabel*)[collectionViewCell viewWithTag:1111];
artistOneOfTableOne.text=[artistOneOfTableOneArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



UILabel *artistTwoOfTableTwo=(UILabel*)[collectionViewCell viewWithTag:2121];
artistTwoOfTableTwo.text=[artistTwoOfTableTwoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];




if ([artistOneOfTableOne.text isEqualToString:@"XYZ" ]) {
    NSMutableArray *array;
    UITableView *TableViewone=(UITableView*)[collectionViewCell viewWithTag:5];

//changing Table View data 
    dateArrayOfTableOne=array;
    [dateArrayOfTableOne addObjectsFromArray:newDateArrayOfTableOne];

    [TableViewone reloadData];
}

return collectionViewCell;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do, I can see there are many things wrong with just this snippet and your description.

Your UIViewController should be conforming to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols for your UITableViews as well as UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource protocols for your UICollectionView.

Ideally, the maximum size for your UICollectionViewCell should be no larger than the viewable space on the window. For example, if there is no UINavigationBar or UITabBar or UIToolBar on your screen, the maximum cell size should be 320x548. That is the width (in points) and height minus status bar of the UIWindow.

If you want the UITableViews to be unique, they should each have their own DataSource (typically an array of values). You will need to include some logic to switch data sources depending on which UITableView is visible and potentially send [UITableView reloadData].

You should be setting the UILabel for your UITableViewCell in the UITableViewDataSource protocol method tableView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: instead of the UICollectionViewDataSource method collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here looking to do a similar thing - to put a different UITableView in each UICollectionView Cell with a datasource. Here's how I did it.

1. I added the tableview as part of the prototype UICollectionViewCell. This is something you don't often do, so it was my gotcha.
2. When the cellForItemAtIndexPath method is called for the collection
   view, I set the tag according to the indexPath.row for each
   tableview. So, something like cell.tableView.tag = indexPath.row.
3. Then, in the tableView datasource, I had a switch statement that handled the tags, and returned the appropriate cells.